# How to insert array of objects into Postgres jsonb column using javascript, knex, objection?

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I have been trying to insert and array of objects into this jsonb column, but I guess the following error message:

```
insert into ... (...) values (...) on conflict ("source_id", "source", "type") do update set ... = ... returning "..." - invalid input syntax for type json
```

The error message is ***invalid input syntax for type json***.

If I try to add an object, it works, but an array of the same object it does not work.

As I am using `objection` together with `knex`, I wonder if I can solve it by setting my `static jsonSchema()` properly.

```
  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: "object",
      required: ["myJsonbColumn"],
      properties: {
        myJsonbColumn: {
          type: "object",
        },
      },
    };
  }
```

Comment: Looks like your insert query does something wrong.  This issue doesn't have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. This is how I had to define my *jsonSchema()*.

I was not sure the `properties` field could accept objects.

```
  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: "object",
      required: ["myJsonbColumn"],
      properties: {
        myJsonbColumn: {
          type: "array",
          items: { type: "object" },
        },
      },
    };
  }
```

So for `myJsonbColumn` (fake column name) I was able to add this object to define its type as `array` and its their inner array items type as `object`.

```
{
  type: "array",
  items: { 
    type: "object" 
  }
}
```

Which makes sense because I was really trying to **save an array of objects in this jsonb column**.